# Using Auth0 with oidc-client and PKCE

Tags: auth0, pkce, oidc-client

I'm using **Auth0** with **oidc-client (latest 1.10.1)**.

Now what I'm trying to do is to use PKCE flow instead of the implicit one and in **AuthModule** I have the following config for **oidc**:

```
NgOidcClientModule.forRoot({
      // prettier-ignore
      oidc_config: {
        authority: environment.sts.authority,
        client_id: environment.sts.clientId,
        redirect_uri: `${environment.appRoot}oidc-login-redirect-callback.html`,
        scope: 'openid profile email',
        response_type: 'code',
        post_logout_redirect_uri: `${environment.appRoot}oidc-logout-redirect-callback.html`,
        silent_redirect_uri: `${environment.appRoot}oidc-silent-renew-redirect-callback.html`,
        accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 10,
        automaticSilentRenew: true,
        metadata: {
          authorization_endpoint: `${environment.sts.authority}authorize?audience=${environment.sts.audience}`,
          userinfo_endpoint: `${environment.sts.authority}userinfo`,
          issuer: environment.sts.authority,
          jwks_uri: `${environment.sts.authority}.well-known/jwks.json`,
          // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
          end_session_endpoint: `${environment.sts.authority}v2/logout?returnTo=${environment.appRootEncoded + 'oidc-logout-redirect-callback.html'}&client_id=${environment.sts.clientId}`
        },
        userStore: (() => new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage })) as any
      }
    }),
```

I had to change **response_type** value from **id_token toke** to **code**.

Another thing I read that I need to change is in the static pages:

```
var config = {
        userStore: new Oidc.WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
        response_mode: 'query',
      };
var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);
```

I understood that I need to add **response_mode: 'query'** for **Oidc.UserManager config**.

All good for now, but I think that I'm missing something because I'm infinitely redirected.

Are there some extra settings I need to do in Auth0 Application?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: downgrade to `oidc-client": "^1.8.2`

Comment:  Nooo! Downgrading is not an option - the package has deprecated, and the new TS one does not allow the implicit flow (for good reason).

Comment: Meanwhile, I've managed to fix it and we also changed the Identity Provider.

Comment: Since changing to the newer [oidc-client-ts](https://github.com/authts/oidc-client-ts) package and switching `response_type` to `code`, I keep getting the error `No state in response at OidcClient.readSigninResponseState` 

Comment: Turns out, it was because the callback URL was using a hash instead of a query ‍♂️ e.g. `/callback#id_token=...` instead of `/callback?id_token=...`.